# Spring bean initialization prior to everyting

Tags: java, spring

I'll try to explain you my problem.

I have a bean which work is to copy files from my classpath to a local folder on the server.
The bean is defined like this and use properties values to know the location where it should copy the files :

```
@Service("wsConfig")
public class WorkspaceConfig implements InitializingBean {
    @Value("path.to.copy")
    String path;
    @Value("classpath.to.copy")
    String folder

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
         /** Do my copy stuff */
    }
}
```

Then i have some beans that depends on the result of that copy and those are defined like this:

```
@PropertySource(value = "file://${user.home}/${path.to.copy}/file.properties")
@Service
public class Bean{
  /** Bean Stuff */
}
```

My problem is that when beans are initialized the file at : `file://${user.home}/${path.to.copy}/file.properties` does not exist when spring link the placeholders with the values.
So i was wondering if there was a way for the first bean to be created and called before any other bean in order to correctly copy those files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be [Depends on another bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) may help

Comment: This will never work. The `@PropertySource` is going to be processed before evaluating the `@Value` annotations and it is not a multi pass process, so simply put it will simply not work. You need to execute that logic before your `ApplicationContext` is even initialized and you would need to place it in, for instance, an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Answer (score -1):

> So i was wondering if there was a way for the first bean to be created
>   and called before any other bean in order to correctly copy those
>   files.

If you just want to control bean creation in such a way that class A should be instantiated only after class B, you can do this.

```
@Service
@DependsOn("B")
public class A {}
```

But, you are asking something more than just instantiation, I would address this use case by spinning up a spring cloud config server.

Answer (score -1):

Don't override `afterPropertiesSet()` method. Rename it something else and remove `@Override` annotation. Rename your method (Usually it is called `init()` but it could be any name) mark that method with `@PostConstruct` annotation and Spring will call it immediately after constructor and all the injections are finished. That should do your trick. Then define your other beans that depend on it with annotation @DependsOn(Your_bean_name)

Comment: Why change the `afterPropertiesSet` for a `@PostConstruct` annotated method?

Comment: Does that mean that the afterPropertiesSet is called after every properties of everybean are set ?

Comment: You are not suppose to implement any Spring interfaces and thus no need to override any of the Spring methods. The annotation @PostConstruct provides you with requested fuctionality

Comment: Changing it to an `@PostConstruct` method doesn't change a thing, as the time of invocation is the same as `afterPropertiesSet`. Regardless it will not work  as the `@PropertySource` already has been processed before that. So this approach regardless of `@PostConstruct` or `InitializingBean` will simply never work.